# how to implement drupal api for user registration and login source site and consumer in other drupal site

Tags: authentication, drupal, drupal-modules

I have two Drupal sites: one named 'source' and the other named 'consumer.'

I have created a custom module for registration and login on the 'source' site, which includes the following endpoints:

'/api/user/register'
'/api/user/login'
On the 'consumer' site, I have created two webforms: one for registration and the other for login. Using the registration webform on the 'consumer' site, I can register users on the 'source' site.

Now, I want the user to be able to log in from the 'consumer' site. It should validate the username and password against the 'source' site's database and authenticate the user on the 'consumer' site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.